# How to pass value from MainActivity to Fragment in Bottom Navigation View in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I am using Firebase in my project, and want to retrieve the data from the database and show it in my Text View in my profile fragment which is a part of Bottom Navigation View. I tried the bundle but it throws error for some reason. So i wanted to know is there any easy way to transfer data from main activity to fragment, specifically one row of Firebase data in different element of the fragment.

Comment: Why not use the call to Firebase directly in the fragment?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface between the the main activity and the fragment when use click to show the fragment ,fire the interface and pass the sting or what you need

another solution you can use a viewModel between the activity and fragment and fire Live data between them

you can also use EventBus